# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment JVM 7.0_45-b18

Tags: java, jvm

Upgraded my JVM to 7.0_45-b18. It now often crashes after Tomcat server runs for a while.

Here is the log file. hs_err_pid2296.log

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f44c71f93ab, pid=2296, tid=139931986904832
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5f93ab]  java_lang_Thread::thread(oopDesc*)+0xb
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f44c00a6000):  JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=2322, stack(0x00007f44744f4000,0x00007f44745f5000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000010

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000010, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x00000006b046f578, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00007f44745f36d0, RBP=0x00007f44745f36d0, RSI=0x0000000000000001, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x00007f44745f38b0, R9 =0x00007f44745f38a0, R10=0x000000000000001a, R11=0x00007f44c7244f10
R12=0x00007f44c009db70, R13=0x0000000000000010, R14=0x0000000000000010, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x00007f44c71f93ab, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f44745f36d0)
0x00007f44745f36d0:   00007f44745f3800 00007f44c72db2e8
0x00007f44745f36e0:   00007f44c7a2de58 00007f44745f3790
0x00007f44745f36f0:   00007f44745f38a0 00007f44745f38b0
0x00007f44745f3700:   00007f44745f38a8 00007f44745f38b4
0x00007f44745f3710:   00007f44c00038e0 00007f44c0008910
0x00007f44745f3720:   00007f44c00a6740 00007f44c009db70
0x00007f44745f3730:   0000000000000011 00000006b046f568
0x00007f44745f3740:   00007f44745f37b0 00007f44c00a6000
0x00007f44745f3750:   00007f44c00a6730 00007f44c00a6740
0x00007f44745f3760:   00007f44c00a6b18 00007f44c009dae0
0x00007f44745f3770:   00000000000003d8 00007f44c00a6b30
0x00007f44745f3780:   00000006b046f578 00007f44c72f8914
0x00007f44745f3790:   00007f44c00a6000 00007f44c009db70
0x00007f44745f37a0:   00007f44c00a6b20 00007f44c00a6b30
0x00007f44745f37b0:   00007f44c00a6f08 00000000000003d8
0x00007f44745f37c0:   00007f44745f3ba0 00007f44c00a6000
0x00007f44745f37d0:   00007f44745f3830 00007f44745f38a0
0x00007f44745f37e0:   0000000000000074 00007f44745f38b0
0x00007f44745f37f0:   00007f44c00a6000 00007f44745f38a8
0x00007f44745f3800:   00007f44745f3880 00007f44c729a180
0x00007f44745f3810:   00007f44745f3830 00007f44745f38b4
0x00007f44745f3820:   00007f4464005920 00007f44c00038e0
0x00007f44745f3830:   00007f44c00a6000 0000000000000000
0x00007f44745f3840:   00007f4400000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f44745f3850:   00007f44745f3880 00007f44745f3ab0
0x00007f44745f3860:   00007f4464005920 00007f44c00a61e8
0x00007f44745f3870:   00007f44745f3920 00007f44c62b9120
0x00007f44745f3880:   00007f44745f38e0 00007f44c60884c3
0x00007f44745f3890:   00007f44745f38c0 00007f44c608bad0
0x00007f44745f38a0:   0000000000030c00 00007f44745f3920
0x00007f44745f38b0:   000000000120eefe 000000000000000c
0x00007f44745f38c0:   0000000000000003 000000000000000c 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f44c71f93ab)
0x00007f44c71f938b:   10 8b 05 5e ef 80 00 83 f8 ff 74 05 48 98 89 34
0x00007f44c71f939b:   07 c9 c3 66 90 48 63 05 d1 61 83 00 55 48 89 e5
0x00007f44c71f93ab:   48 8b 04 07 c9 c3 90 66 66 66 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84
0x00007f44c71f93bb:   00 00 00 00 00 48 63 05 b1 61 83 00 55 48 89 e5 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000006b046f578 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f44745f36d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f44c00a6000
RBP=0x00007f44745f36d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f44c00a6000
RSI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f44745f38b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f44c00a6000
R9 =0x00007f44745f38a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f44c00a6000
R10=0x000000000000001a is an unknown value
R11=0x00007f44c7244f10: <offset 0x644f10> in /hpdev/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f44c6c00000
R12=0x00007f44c009db70 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00007f44744f4000,0x00007f44745f5000],  sp=0x00007f44745f36d0,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x5f93ab]  java_lang_Thread::thread(oopDesc*)+0xb
V  [libjvm.so+0x6db2e8]  JvmtiEnv::GetThreadGroupChildren(_jobject*, int*, _jobject***, int*, _jobject***)+0x208
V  [libjvm.so+0x69a180]  jvmti_GetThreadGroupChildren+0x160
C  [libjdwp.so+0x94c3]  children+0xa3
C  [libjdwp.so+0x118e6]  debugLoop_run+0x2b6
C  [libjdwp.so+0x2432f]  attachThread+0x2f
V  [libjvm.so+0x6f45c7]  JvmtiAgentThread::call_start_function()+0x97
V  [libjvm.so+0x94d38f]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0xdf
V  [libjvm.so+0x94d495]  JavaThread::run()+0xf5
V  [libjvm.so+0x815288]  java_start(Thread*)+0x108


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f44081b4800 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-EventThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2872, stack(0x00007f4385d71000,0x00007f4385e72000)]
  0x00007f44080fb000 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-SendThread(localhost:2181)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2871, stack(0x00007f4385468000,0x00007f4385569000)]
  0x00007f44080fc800 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-SendThread(localhost:2181)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2869, stack(0x00007f438576b000,0x00007f438586c000)]
  0x00007f44082c4000 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-SendThread(localhost:2181)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2867, stack(0x00007f4387387000,0x00007f4387488000)]
  0x00007f44081b1800 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-SendThread(localhost:2181)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2865, stack(0x00007f438566a000,0x00007f438576b000)]
  0x00007f44081b4000 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-SendThread(localhost:2181)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2863, stack(0x00007f438596d000,0x00007f4385a6e000)]
  0x00007f44081b1000 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-SendThread(localhost:2181)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2861, stack(0x00007f4385c70000,0x00007f4385d71000)]
  0x00007f44080f9800 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-SendThread(localhost:2181)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2859, stack(0x00007f438586c000,0x00007f438596d000)]
  0x00007f44082c3000 JavaThread "IPC Client (47) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:59065 from yfang" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2827, stack(0x00007f438677b000,0x00007f438687c000)]
  0x00007f44200a4000 JavaThread "pool-12-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2826, stack(0x00007f4385e72000,0x00007f4385f73000)]
  0x00007f43f000c000 JavaThread "HTablePool-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2825, stack(0x00007f4385b6f000,0x00007f4385c70000)]
  0x00007f4408175000 JavaThread "IPC Client (47) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:39629 from yfang" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2814, stack(0x00007f4387488000,0x00007f4387589000)]
  0x00007f4408219800 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-EventThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2787, stack(0x00007f4385a6e000,0x00007f4385b6f000)]
  0x00007f440824b800 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-1206643246-1-SendThread(localhost:2181)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2786, stack(0x00007f4386c80000,0x00007f4386d81000)]
  0x00007f4448024800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2777, stack(0x00007f4387b8f000,0x00007f4387c90000)]
  0x00007f4448023800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2776, stack(0x00007f4386074000,0x00007f4386175000)]
  0x00007f4448020800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2775, stack(0x00007f438687c000,0x00007f438697d000)]
  0x00007f444801f800 JavaThread "Timer-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2774, stack(0x00007f4385f73000,0x00007f4386074000)]
  0x00007f4448014000 JavaThread "Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2735, stack(0x00007f4386276000,0x00007f4386377000)]
  0x00007f43cc014000 JavaThread "Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2734, stack(0x00007f4386a7e000,0x00007f4386b7f000)]
  0x00007f442c04a000 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-550133108-3" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=2733, stack(0x00007f4386377000,0x00007f4386478000)]
  0x00007f4400022000 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-550133108-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2732, stack(0x00007f4387e92000,0x00007f4387f93000)]
  0x00007f43e81b3800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2729, stack(0x00007f4386478000,0x00007f4386579000)]
  0x00007f43e81b1800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2728, stack(0x00007f4386579000,0x00007f438667a000)]
  0x00007f43e83e5000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2727, stack(0x00007f438667a000,0x00007f438677b000)]
  0x00007f43e83e4000 JavaThread "Timer-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2726, stack(0x00007f438697d000,0x00007f4386a7e000)]
  0x00007f43940ed800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2717, stack(0x00007f4387589000,0x00007f438768a000)]
  0x00007f4424030000 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2716, stack(0x00007f4387c90000,0x00007f4387d91000)]
  0x00007f43940ec000 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2709, stack(0x00007f4386b7f000,0x00007f4386c80000)]
  0x00007f43940eb800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2708, stack(0x00007f438768a000,0x00007f438778b000)]
  0x00007f439c139800 JavaThread "frontPage-7" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2699, stack(0x00007f4386d81000,0x00007f4386e82000)]
  0x00007f439c138000 JavaThread "frontPage-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2698, stack(0x00007f4386e82000,0x00007f4386f83000)]
  0x00007f439c136800 JavaThread "frontPage-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2697, stack(0x00007f4386f83000,0x00007f4387084000)]
  0x00007f439c134800 JavaThread "frontPage-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2696, stack(0x00007f4387084000,0x00007f4387185000)]
  0x00007f439c132800 JavaThread "frontPage-5" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2695, stack(0x00007f4387185000,0x00007f4387286000)]
  0x00007f439c132000 JavaThread "frontPage-3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2694, stack(0x00007f4387286000,0x00007f4387387000)]
  0x00007f439c130000 JavaThread "frontPage-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2693, stack(0x00007f4387f93000,0x00007f4388094000)]
  0x00007f43e83e0800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2678, stack(0x00007f438778b000,0x00007f438788c000)]
  0x00007f43e83de800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2677, stack(0x00007f438788c000,0x00007f438798d000)]
  0x00007f43e83bb000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2676, stack(0x00007f438798d000,0x00007f4387a8e000)]
  0x00007f43e83ba000 JavaThread "Timer-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2675, stack(0x00007f4387a8e000,0x00007f4387b8f000)]
  0x00007f43f8208800 JavaThread "IPC Client (47) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:59065 from yfang" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2670, stack(0x00007f4387d91000,0x00007f4387e92000)]
  0x00007f43f8104000 JavaThread "IPC Client (47) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:39629 from yfang" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2667, stack(0x00007f4388094000,0x00007f4388195000)]
  0x00007f43f8042000 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-550133108-1-EventThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2666, stack(0x00007f4388568000,0x00007f4388669000)]
  0x00007f43f8446800 JavaThread "DataRouterContext-550133108-1-SendThread(localhost:2181)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2665, stack(0x00007f4388669000,0x00007f438876a000)]
  0x00007f43e80d5000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2664, stack(0x00007f438876a000,0x00007f438886b000)]
  0x00007f43e80d3800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2663, stack(0x00007f438886b000,0x00007f438896c000)]
  0x00007f43e80d2000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2662, stack(0x00007f438896c000,0x00007f4388a6d000)]
  0x00007f43e80d1000 JavaThread "Timer-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2661, stack(0x00007f4388a6d000,0x00007f4388b6e000)]
  0x00007f43e8197800 JavaThread "Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2660, stack(0x00007f4388b6e000,0x00007f4388c6f000)]
  0x00007f44c02ed000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, 
  0x00007f4438ec6000 JavaThread "scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2389, stack(0x00007f43fe97c000,0x00007f43fea7d000)]
  0x00007f4438ec3800 JavaThread "SimpleThreadPoolWorker-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2384, stack(0x00007f43fea7d000,0x00007f43feb7e000)]
  0x00007f4438ec1800 JavaThread "SimpleThreadPoolWorker-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2383, stack(0x00007f43feb7e000,0x00007f43fec7f000)]
  0x00007f4438ebf800 JavaThread "SimpleThreadPoolWorker-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2382, stack(0x00007f43fec7f000,0x00007f43fed80000)]
  0x00007f4438ebd000 JavaThread "SimpleThreadPoolWorker-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2381, stack(0x00007f43fed80000,0x00007f43fee81000)]
  0x00007f4438ebb800 JavaThread "SimpleThreadPoolWorker-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2380, stack(0x00007f43fee81000,0x00007f43fef82000)]
  0x00007f4438eaf800 JavaThread "SimpleThreadPoolWorker-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2379, stack(0x00007f43fef82000,0x00007f43ff083000)]
  0x00007f4438ead800 JavaThread "SimpleThreadPoolWorker-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2378, stack(0x00007f43ff083000,0x00007f43ff184000)]
  0x00007f4438eac000 JavaThread "SimpleThreadPoolWorker-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2377, stack(0x00007f43ff184000,0x00007f43ff285000)]
  0x00007f4438eb5800 JavaThread "countArchiveFlushSchedulerDb-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2376, stack(0x00007f43ff285000,0x00007f43ff386000)]
  0x00007f4438ecb800 JavaThread "countArchiveFlushSchedulerMemory-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2375, stack(0x00007f43ff386000,0x00007f43ff487000)]
  0x00007f43e80ae800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2374, stack(0x00007f43ff487000,0x00007f43ff588000)]

 PSYoungGen      total 2447360K, used 3763K [0x00000006aaa80000, 0x0000000755580000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 2098176K, 0% used [0x00000006aaa80000,0x00000006aaa80000,0x000000072ab80000)
  from space 349184K, 1% used [0x000000072ab80000,0x000000072af2cde0,0x0000000740080000)
  to   space 349184K, 0% used [0x0000000740080000,0x0000000740080000,0x0000000755580000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592576K, used 72K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000555580000, 0x00000006aaa80000)
  object space 5592576K, 0% used [0x0000000400000000,0x0000000400012010,0x0000000555580000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 8790K [0x00000003e0000000, 0x00000003e1500000, 0x0000000400000000)
  object space 21504K, 40% used [0x00000003e0000000,0x00000003e0895ab8,0x00000003e1500000)
Event: 0.621 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 2447360K, used 0K [0x00000006aaa80000, 0x0000000755580000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 2098176K, 0% used [0x00000006aaa80000,0x00000006aaa80000,0x000000072ab80000)
  from space 349184K, 0% used [0x000000072ab80000,0x000000072ab80000,0x0000000740080000)
  to   space 349184K, 0% used [0x0000000740080000,0x0000000740080000,0x0000000755580000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592576K, used 3563K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000555580000, 0x00000006aaa80000)
  object space 5592576K, 0% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000040037ac78,0x0000000555580000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 8788K [0x00000003e0000000, 0x00000003e1500000, 0x0000000400000000)
  object space 21504K, 40% used [0x00000003e0000000,0x00000003e0895270,0x00000003e1500000)
}
Event: 10.558 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 2447360K, used 2098176K [0x00000006aaa80000, 0x0000000755580000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 2098176K, 100% used [0x00000006aaa80000,0x000000072ab80000,0x000000072ab80000)
  from space 349184K, 0% used [0x000000072ab80000,0x000000072ab80000,0x0000000740080000)
  to   space 349184K, 0% used [0x0000000740080000,0x0000000740080000,0x0000000755580000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592576K, used 3563K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000555580000, 0x00000006aaa80000)
  object space 5592576K, 0% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000040037ac78,0x0000000555580000)
 PSPermGen       total 62464K, used 62250K [0x00000003e0000000, 0x00000003e3d00000, 0x0000000400000000)
  object space 62464K, 99% used [0x00000003e0000000,0x00000003e3ccaa30,0x00000003e3d00000)
Event: 10.638 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 2447360K, used 111095K [0x00000006aaa80000, 0x0000000755580000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 2098176K, 0% used [0x00000006aaa80000,0x00000006aaa80000,0x000000072ab80000)
  from space 349184K, 31% used [0x0000000740080000,0x0000000746cfdfb0,0x0000000755580000)
  to   space 349184K, 0% used [0x000000072ab80000,0x000000072ab80000,0x0000000740080000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592576K, used 3635K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000555580000, 0x00000006aaa80000)
  object space 5592576K, 0% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000040038cc88,0x0000000555580000)
 PSPermGen       total 62464K, used 62250K [0x00000003e0000000, 0x00000003e3d00000, 0x0000000400000000)
  object space 62464K, 99% used [0x00000003e0000000,0x00000003e3ccaa30,0x00000003e3d00000)
}
Event: 25.458 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=4 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 2447360K, used 2209271K [0x00000006aaa80000, 0x0000000755580000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 2098176K, 100% used [0x00000006aaa80000,0x000000072ab80000,0x000000072ab80000)
  from space 349184K, 31% used [0x0000000740080000,0x0000000746cfdfb0,0x0000000755580000)
  to   space 349184K, 0% used [0x000000072ab80000,0x000000072ab80000,0x0000000740080000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592576K, used 3635K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000555580000, 0x00000006aaa80000)
  object space 5592576K, 0% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000040038cc88,0x0000000555580000)
 PSPermGen       total 112128K, used 112092K [0x00000003e0000000, 0x00000003e6d80000, 0x0000000400000000)
  object space 112128K, 99% used [0x00000003e0000000,0x00000003e6d77168,0x00000003e6d80000)
Event: 25.538 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=4 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 2447360K, used 132448K [0x00000006aaa80000, 0x0000000755580000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 2098176K, 0% used [0x00000006aaa80000,0x00000006aaa80000,0x000000072ab80000)
  from space 349184K, 37% used [0x000000072ab80000,0x0000000732cd80f8,0x0000000740080000)
  to   space 349184K, 0% used [0x0000000740080000,0x0000000740080000,0x0000000755580000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592576K, used 3643K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000555580000, 0x00000006aaa80000)
  object space 5592576K, 0% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000040038ec88,0x0000000555580000)
 PSPermGen       total 112128K, used 112092K [0x00000003e0000000, 0x00000003e6d80000, 0x0000000400000000)
  object space 112128K, 99% used [0x00000003e0000000,0x00000003e6d77168,0x00000003e6d80000)
}
Event: 34.248 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 2447360K, used 2230624K [0x00000006aaa80000, 0x0000000755580000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 2098176K, 100% used [0x00000006aaa80000,0x000000072ab80000,0x000000072ab80000)
  from space 349184K, 37% used [0x000000072ab80000,0x0000000732cd80f8,0x0000000740080000)
  to   space 349184K, 0% used [0x0000000740080000,0x0000000740080000,0x0000000755580000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592576K, used 3643K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000555580000, 0x00000006aaa80000)
  object space 5592576K, 0% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000040038ec88,0x0000000555580000)
 PSPermGen       total 164864K, used 164507K [0x00000003e0000000, 0x00000003ea100000, 0x0000000400000000)
  object space 164864K, 99% used [0x00000003e0000000,0x00000003ea0a6e38,0x00000003ea100000)
Event: 34.407 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 2447360K, used 192293K [0x00000006aaa80000, 0x00000007d5680000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 2098176K, 0% used [0x00000006aaa80000,0x00000006aaa80000,0x000000072ab80000)
  from space 349184K, 55% used [0x0000000740080000,0x000000074bc496a8,0x0000000755580000)
  to   space 349184K, 0% used [0x000000072ab80000,0x000000072ab80000,0x0000000740080000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592576K, used 3659K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000555580000, 0x00000006aaa80000)
  object space 5592576K, 0% used [0x0000000400000000,0x0000000400392c88,0x0000000555580000)
 PSPermGen       total 164864K, used 164507K [0x00000003e0000000, 0x00000003ea100000, 0x0000000400000000)
  object space 164864K, 99% used [0x00000003e0000000,0x00000003ea0a6e38,0x00000003ea100000)
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 34.956 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd283e94 method=java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Class; @ 72
Event: 34.956 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd283e94 method=java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Class; @ 72
Event: 34.956 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd1e1a58 method=org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.lookup(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 143
Event: 34.956 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd1e14f4 method=org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.lookup(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 143
Event: 34.970 Thread 0x00007f441c00f000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd1e1a58 method=org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.lookup(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 143
Event: 34.970 Thread 0x00007f441c00f000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd1e14f4 method=org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.lookup(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 143
Event: 34.984 Thread 0x00007f441c00f000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd1e1a58 method=org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.lookup(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 143
Event: 34.984 Thread 0x00007f441c00f000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd1e14f4 method=org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.lookup(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 143
Event: 35.000 Thread 0x00007f441c00f000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd1e1a58 method=org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.lookup(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 143
Event: 35.000 Thread 0x00007f441c00f000 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x00007f44bd1e14f4 method=org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.lookup(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 143

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 34.712 Thread 0x00007f441c00f000 Threw 0x00000006b03daae0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 34.712 Thread 0x00007f441c00f000 Threw 0x00000006b03db1d0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 34.790 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Threw 0x00000006b19372d0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 34.790 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Threw 0x00000006b1937b70 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 34.791 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Threw 0x00000006b195a870 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 34.791 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Threw 0x00000006b195b158 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 34.820 Thread 0x00007f4408177000 Threw 0x00000006af95d610 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 34.820 Thread 0x00007f4408177000 Threw 0x00000006af95de48 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 34.956 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Threw 0x00000006b3fae768 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 34.956 Thread 0x00007f442c04a000 Threw 0x00000006b3faf0a8 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 35.011 Executing VM operation: BulkRevokeBias
Event: 35.012 Executing VM operation: BulkRevokeBias done
Event: 35.012 Executing VM operation: BulkRevokeBias
Event: 35.012 Executing VM operation: BulkRevokeBias done
Event: 35.014 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 35.014 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 35.014 Thread 0x00007f44081b3000 Thread exited: 0x00007f44081b3000
Event: 35.016 loading class 0x00007f44383e39b0
Event: 35.016 Executing VM operation: BulkRevokeBias
Event: 35.016 loading class 0x00007f44383e39b0 done


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 13117744                           /hpdev/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 13117744                           /hpdev/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
02201000-02222000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3e0000000-3ea480000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3ea480000-400000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
400000000-555580000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
555580000-6aaa80000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
6aaa80000-7d5680000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7d5680000-800000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4385466000-7f4385468000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4385468000-7f438546b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f438546b000-7f4385569000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:2871]
7f4385569000-7f438556c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f438556c000-7f438566a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f438566a000-7f438566d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f438566d000-7f438576b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:2865]
7f438576b000-7f438576e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f438576e000-7f438586c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:2869]
7f438586c000-7f438586f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f438586f000-7f438596d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:2859]
7f438596d000-7f4385970000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Comment: It looks like you let the smoke out.  The JVM doesn't work so well when you let the smoke out.  In all seriousness, it looks like something happened in the `com.hotpads.datarouter.client.imp.hbase.factory.HBaseSimpleClientFactory` class.  The core was triggered from libjvm.so, but you have ulimits on, so no core file.  Does the app always fail in the same spot?  You might be able to garner some info by enabling the core and analyzing it, but I doubt it will be useful if you haven't done that sort of thing before.  Does the code run on other servers?

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of `/home/yfang/hs_err_pid2296.log` (the error report file) - especially the "stack" section may prove interesting, and the Tomcat version.

Comment: Also, what did you upgrade from? Were you using a 32 bit JVM before? Do you have any native code running in the JVM?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention...SIGSEGV is, I believe, an access violation, which usually means your application tried to access memory that did not belong to it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application is run with "Debug" option and your IDE(or any monitoring tool) kills the application:

```
V  [libjvm.so+0x5f93ab]  java_lang_Thread::thread(oopDesc*)+0xb
V  [libjvm.so+0x6db2e8]  JvmtiEnv::GetThreadGroupChildren(_jobject*, int*, _jobject***, int*, _jobject***)+0x208
V  [libjvm.so+0x69a180]  jvmti_GetThreadGroupChildren+0x160
C  [libjdwp.so+0x94c3]  children+0xa3
C  [libjdwp.so+0x118e6]  debugLoop_run+0x2b6
C  [libjdwp.so+0x2432f]  attachThread+0x2f
V  [libjvm.so+0x6f45c7]  JvmtiAgentThread::call_start_function()+0x97
V  [libjvm.so+0x94d38f]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0xdf
V  [libjvm.so+0x94d495]  JavaThread::run()+0xf5
V  [libjvm.so+0x815288]  java_start(Thread*)+0x108
```

As a workaround you can

- avoid using debug mode for the application
- change the jvm

In order to solve this problem it is important to have the following information:

- is it reproducible under other JVMs?
- is it reproducible with/without JVM options: -server, -Xint